# How to alphabetically sort a nested dictionary by key without using OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, nested

Say I have this nested dictionary:

```
people = {
          Kamara: {'sex': 'Male', 'alias': 'John', 'age': '27'},
          Alison: {'age': '21', 'alias': 'Marie', 'sex': 'Female'},
          Oliver: {'alias': 'Marie', 'age': '25', 'sex': 'Female'}
         }
```

I want to alphabetically sort **everything**. I mean not only the main keys, but also the sub-keys, without using the OrderedDict library. The final result should be this:

```
people = {
          Alison: {'age': '21', 'alias': 'Marie', 'sex': 'Female'},
          Kamara: {'age': '27', 'alias': 'John', 'sex': 'Male'},
          Oliver: {'age': '25', 'alias': 'Marie', 'sex': 'Female'}
        }
```

This is what I have:

```
people = {key: dict(sorted(val.items(), key=lambda ele: ele[1])) for key, val in people.items()}
```

but I get this error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: The names need to be in quotes

Comment: If one of the comments below has given you the result you wanted then please mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dict comprehension can do this.

```py
people = {
          'Kamara': {'sex': 'Male', 'alias': 'John', 'age': '27'},
          'Alison': {'age': '21', 'alias': 'Marie', 'sex': 'Female'},
          'Oliver': {'alias': 'Marie', 'age': '25', 'sex': 'Female'}
         }


new_dict = {k: {x:y for x,y in sorted(v.items())} for k,v in sorted(people.items())}

print(new_dict)

{'Alison': {'age': '21', 'alias': 'Marie', 'sex': 'Female'}, 
'Kamara': {'age': '27', 'alias': 'John', 'sex': 'Male'}, 
'Oliver': {'age': '25', 'alias': 'Marie', 'sex': 'Female'}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: As I said in my first comment to your post, your keys also need quotes @tajir12457

Answer (score 0):

```
f =  = {k: dict(sorted(v.items(), key=lambda item: item[0])) for k, v in sorted(people.items(), key=lambda item: item[0]) }
```

Output:

```
{'Alison': {'age': '21', 'alias': 'Marie', 'sex': 'Female'}, 
'Kamara': {'age': '27', 'alias': 'John', 'sex': 'Male'},
'Oliver': {'age': '25', 'alias': 'Marie', 'sex': 'Female'}}
```